# Setting file path in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, log4j

In log4j.xml at local, i am trying to set path as

```
<appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="C:\\logs\\app_error.log" />
</appender>
```

it is working fine.

but for server, i need to create the log file under "/mainroot/projects/log".
I am trying

```
<appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="\\mainroot\\projects\\log\\app_error.log" />
    </appender>
```

but this is not working. Plese help to set the path.

Comment: What operating system does this server use? Is it unix or linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566555/how-to-log-messages-in-separate-files-depending-on-their-level/

Answer (score 1):

```
<appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="\\mainroot\\projects\\log\\app_error.log" />
    </appender>
```

Unix uses "/" as a path separator. Try this:

```
<appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/mainroot/projects/log/app_error.log" />
    </appender>
```